# Incorrect prediction for nearest neighbor algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, prediction, nearest-neighbor

My task was to: Complete the code for the function predict, which, given the array of  ×
distances, the labels, and k, predicts the M labels for the unlabeled images, based off of the labels of its k-nearest neighbors.

Suppose k=5. Given an unlabeled image, we want to identify the 5 labeled images that are nearest to it (based on L2-distance), and consult their labels (specifically their class-IDs for cifar10). The most common label will be selected as the label used to classify the unlabeled image. For example, suppose the labels for the 5 nearest neighbors are: 2, 0, 2, 2, 8. Then the predicted label for this unlabeled image will be 2.

If there is a tie among the k labels, the lowest-value class-ID among the tied labels should be used.

This was my code:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

def predict(dists, labels, k):
    # Find the indices of the k-nearest neighbors for each unlabeled image, sorted by descending distance
    nearest = np.argsort(dists, axis=1)[:, :k]

    # Get the labels of the nearest neighbors
    nearest_labels = labels[nearest]

    # Count the occurrences of each class ID in the nearest neighbors
    counts = [Counter(row) for row in nearest_labels]

    # Get the most common class ID for each row of nearest neighbors
    most_common = []
    for count in counts:
        # Check for ties and break them by choosing the label with the lowest value
        max_count = max(count.values())
        possible_labels = [label for label, count in count.items() if count == max_count]
        chosen_label = min(possible_labels)
        most_common.append(chosen_label)

    return np.array(most_common)
    pass
```

It gets the error:

```
Calling 
    predict(array([[0., 1., 1., 1.]]), array([0, 1, 1, 0]), 3)
produced an incorrect result.

Expected a shape-(1,) array with value:
array([0])

Got a shape-(1,) array with value:
array([1])
```

Can somebody explain to me, or help me fix the problem in my code. I've been stuck at it for a while.

I have tried implementing different tiebreaks, and using different methods